# Nice scroll to wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am converting html5 to wordpress Theme.
I want to use custom scroll for wordpress.
The code  `<script src="jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>`

DEPENDENCIES
It's a plugin for the jquery framework, you need to include jquery in your scripts.

I will use

```
"<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>"
```

Will it work just by that 
What about below code?

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("html").niceScroll();
  }
);
```

EXAMPLES
1. Simple mode, it styles document scrollbar (html element prefered):

Where to enter this to make it work?

After enqueuing , do i need it again to add in header.php
Explanation will be helpful.

Comment: you should ask this question in the appropriate stack website: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: NOBODY replies there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to navigate your wordpress theme files you can easily add nice scroll file "jquery.nicescroll.js" into the theme where other js files is preferred and then register and enqueue it in the functions.php file

```
wp_register_script('nice-js',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js',array('jquery'),'1.0.0',true );
wp_enqueue_script('nice-js');
```

and finally add it into the theme main js file

Like so:

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
  //nicescroll
  $(function() {
      $("html").niceScroll();
  });
});
```